# Given an equation with one parameter, how do I use NSolve to solve it for many values of the parameter?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I was wondering if there was a way to use the *Mathematica* `NSolve` command to solve an equation that has a parameter with various values. An example of which is:

```
parameter = {1,2,3,4,5};

equation = x + parameter;

NSolve[equation == 0, {x}]
```

The output should be:

> ```
> {-1,-2,-3,-4,-5}
> ```

Obviously, my `NSolve` expression does not give the above output, but if it did, it would make my world MUCH easier. As my actual equations are much more complex and my parameter lists can sometimes contain a lot of values, copy and paste has been tedious, to say the least!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _Mathematica_ does the right thing, and `NSolve` should return a empty list, because the equations `{1 + x == 0, 2 + x == 0, 3 + x == 0, 4 + x == 0, 5 + x == 0}` are incompatible with each other. What you really mean is solving them _one by one_ , not simultaneously. In this case, `NSolve[# == 0, {x}] & /@ equation` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using replacement rules in the following fashion:

```
NSolve[x + parameter == 0, x] /. parameter -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

gives you:

```
{{x -> {-1, -2, -3, -4, -5}}}
```

Comment: Only potential caveat: This actually calls `Solve` rather than `NSolve`.

Comment: Can you further explain that?

Comment: You are solving for generic `parameter`. `NSolve` notices symbolic content and passes onto `Solve`, which returns the generic solution. The value replacement is done after that. You can see that exact numbers are returned, where `NSolve` would return a machine precision solution (as e.g. in my solution). Those are two quite different paths evaluation-wise, and depending on the complexity of the expression, results may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSolve[x + # == 0, x] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4}
x /. %
Flatten[%]
```

> {{{x -> -1.}}, {{x -> -2.}}, {{x -> -3.}}, {{x -> -4.}}}
>
> {{-1.}, {-2.}, {-3.}, {-4.}}
>
> {-1., -2., -3., -4.}

Comment: What if I have multiple parameters? Not just one #